# navigationBarTitle with variable gives various random errors

Tags: swiftui

Does anyone know why I get errors when using a variable for my navigationBarTitle ?
The error changes depending on where I put this line of code, or what the main container is.  Currently I get the usual **'CGFloat' is not convertible to 'CGFloat?'**

But if I swap the navigationBarTitle with the padding then I get **Ambiguous reference to member 'navigationBarTitle(_:displayMode:)'**

If I swap the sectionName for "" then the compiler is happy.

```
struct TestView : View {

    private var sectionName = "Hello"

    var body : some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Hello")
        }
        .navigationBarTitle(sectionName, displayMode:.inline)
        .padding(.horizontal, 12.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, to see the real error you may update Xcode to 11.4 version - it shows errors better. 
The second - if you will go to `SwiftUI` framework, you will see:

```
public func navigationBarTitle(_ titleKey: LocalizedStringKey, displayMode: NavigationBarItem.TitleDisplayMode) -> some View
```

so, the error is that you use `String` instead of `LocalizedStringKey`

the solution is:

```swift
// replace this
//private var sectionName = "Hello" 
// to this:
private var sectionName: LocalizedStringKey = "Hello"
```

Comment: Thank you! I should have worked that out myself and probably could have if command click on navigationBarTitle didn't just show me a blank screen 90% of the time.